# WIF ADFS Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif, saml, adfs

I am authenticating my wbesite againt an ADFS server using WIF. All seems to work fine, I get pass the login screen and I am redirected to the Success page. However, I am told I don't have access to my website resources like javascript, image and css files.

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with status 401 (Unauthorized)"

Thank you
Virgil

Comment: have you added it in your audienceUris?

Comment: The 'Success.aspx" page is displayed. The javascript and css files are not.